# Ошибка компиляции: illegal start of expression

Tags: java, компиляция, синтаксис

Возникает ошибка при создании:

```
(9:9)illegal start of expression.
```

В чем моя ошибка?

**Имеется код:**

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    Scanner scc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int firstNum = whatnumber();
        int secodNum = whatnumber();
        char znak = Goperation();
        int resault = resaultX();
        System.out.print(resault);


    }
    public static int whatnumber() {
        System.out.print("Введите число: ");
        int num;
        num = scc.nextInt();
    }
    public static void Goperation() {
        System.out.print("Введите знак: ");
        char znakL;
        znakL = scc.hasNext();
    }
    public static void resaultX(int firstNum, int secondNum, char operation){
        int resault;
        switch (operation) {
            case "+":
                resault = firstNum + secondNum;
                break;
            case "-":
                resault = firstNum - secondNum;
                break;
            case "/":
                resault = firstNum / secondNum;
                break;
            case "*":
                resault = firstNum * secondNum;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нельзя объявлять методы внутри методов, а у вас в `main` запихан ещё один `main` и куча других методов.

Comment: У вас все очень много ошибок, вы нашли код в интернете и не понимаете его? Напишите свой. Сначала напишите ввод числа, запустите, проверьте, сделайте отладку, выведите числа на экран. Затем когда всё будет работать как надо напишите ввод знака и т.д.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, я сначала тоже подумал что ошибка только в этом, но оказалось, что почти всё неправильно. Неправильно работает ввод знака, сравнение с символом в `switch`, неправильное возвращаемое значение у `Goperation`, в общем много.

Comment: Только учусь, первую неделю.
Я могу ошибаться или делать ошибки, спасибо. Вы помогли, я просто перенервничал.
Ваши советы помогают конструктивнее, чем то что я делал сам. Огромное спасибо, вышли НОВЫЕ ошибки, но они новые.

Comment: @ШурокПетров по какому учебнику учитесь?

Answer (score 2):

1. Как и сказали main внутри main - нельзя писать метод внутри метода
2. Не понятно вообще это вам нужно(вторая строка с main) - просто удалите
3. Даже учитывая что вы неправильно написали второй раз main - тут вы еще не закрыли скобку, всегда открывающиеся скобки нужно закрывать.
4. В методе `Goperation()` - `scc.hasNext()` - возращает `boolean` - правда/ не правда, т.е. вы не записываете чар, а проверяете наличие.
   "Существует и метод `hasNext()`, проверяющий остались ли в потоке ввода какие-то символы."
   http://kostin.ws/java/java-input-stream.html

   5. Если вы используете char - то нужно указывать `''`, вместо `""` - они используются для `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   package My.Package;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    Scanner scc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int firstNum = whatnumber();
        int secodNum = whatnumber();
        String znak = Goperation();
        int resault = resaultX(firstNum,secodNum,znak);
        System.out.print(resault);


    }
    public static int whatnumber() {
        Scanner scc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите число: ");
        int num;
        num = scc.nextInt();
        return  num;
    }
    public static String Goperation() {
        Scanner scc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите знак: ");
        String znakL;
        znakL = scc.nextLine();
        return  znakL;
    }
    public static int resaultX(int firstNum, int secondNum, String operation){
        int resault;
        switch (operation) {
            case "+":
                resault = firstNum + secondNum;
                break;
            case "-":
                resault = firstNum - secondNum;
                break;
            case "/":
                resault = firstNum / secondNum;
                break;
            case "*":
                resault = firstNum * secondNum;
                break;
            default: resault = 0;
        }
        return resault;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`(9:9)illegal start of expression.` - говорит что это ошибка компиляции. Структура программы на Java имеет определённый [синтаксис](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax). Этот синтаксис определяет правила использования элементов языка в вашей программе.

Java это очень сложный язык. Конечно читать сразу [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) будет сложно, поэтому [новичкам рекомендуют начинить](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/tutorialLearningPaths.html#newtojava) с пониманием базовых концепций. Потом уже переходить к кодированию.